# Erro "phonegap run android"

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou tento problemas para executar o comando $phonegap run android.
Dá o seguinte erro:

> ```
>    C:\Users\maquina05\App_Oliver>phonegap run android
> [phonegap] executing 'cordova run android ' ...
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
>
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib
>
> Unzipping C:\Users\maquina05\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\53l0mv9mggp
> 9q5m2ip574m21oh\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to C:\Users\maquina05\.gradle\wrapper\dist
> s\gradle-2.14.1-all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh
>
> Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
> essManager.java:78)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
> essManager.java:65)
>         ... 3 more
>
> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipExceptio
> n: zip file is empty
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
> essManager.java:78)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
>         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
> essManager.java:65)
>         ... 3 more
> ```

Excutando $cordova run android ,da exatamente o mesmo erro.

Como posso resolver este problema?

---

Denis.
Fiz o seu procedimento e deu o seguinte erro.

```
C:\Users\maquina05\App_Oliver>cordova build
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
...............................................................................
Unzipping C:\Users\maquina05\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-   all\53l0mv9mggp
9q5m2ip574m21oh\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to     C:\Users\maquina05\.gradle\wrapper\dist
s\gradle-2.14.1-all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be   faster).

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at     https://docs.gradle.org/
2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap.
```

Ja criei o gradle nas variaveis de ambiente e quando eu dou o comando:

```
$gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-03-03 19:45:41 UTC
Revision:     9eb76efdd3d034dc506c719dac2955efb5ff9a93

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_111 (Oracle Corporation 25.111-b14)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 x86
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536105/5325043) resposta no StackOverflow em inglês, segundo a mensagem de erro, o arquivo está corrompido.

Apague o conteúdo de `C:\Users\maquina05\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh` e rode o comando `cordova build` novamente

---

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap.
```

Significa que não há memória suficiente para inicializar a VM, dei uma olhada em alguns fórums a solução que encontrei para o segundo problema é criar um arquivo `project.properties` e adicionar o conteúdo:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Outra forma de definir esse valor é pela variável de ambiente `GRADLE_OPTS`, o valor dela deve ser `-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m`